# Get java.awt.Robot to interact only with the test app

Tags: java, unit-testing, jython, awtrobot

I doubt whether there's a solution to this but thought I'd ask anyway.

`java.awt.Robot` is very useful for unit testing, to simulate user input/action. The trouble is you can't then do anything else on your comp for the duration of the test, because the Robot keyPresses, etc., will then start happening in the application which has focus at the time, not in the app which you are subjecting to testing...

Even if you precede every such Robot command with `requestFocus` or some such this is not a solution for the simple reason that between such commands, which must be run in the EDT, and the Robot's command, which must be run in a non-EDT thread, you may happen to do sthg (keyboard or mouse action) which will transfer focus outside the test app.

I think therefore that a Robot which knows it must interact only with the test app is kind of essential.  Without that you "lose" your machine for the duration of the tests.

Running the tests in a VM might be one solution - does anyone know of any other?

Comment: Do a Google search for "desktop application testing" and see what you can come up with.  I think all similar testing tools require exclusive use of the workstation.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion ... I tried one or two such as |"desktop application testing"  user input confined to app| ... to no avail...

Comment: Use a headless X server like Xvfb  (X Window Virtual Framebuffer). But what is wrong with using a VM?

Comment: @Würgspaß thanks, I'll look into this. My prob with using a VM is that, unfortunately, I am stuck for the moment in a Windoze box.  Every couple of years I try to get into Linux and find it all too confusing, without a colleague to help with trickier things.  I'm not an IT professional so have to rely on forums, etc, and I have always found that to do anything but the most basic stuff I get stuck.  In this case I'd have to install Java  and Jython and deal with an M$ Access ODBC connection.  To use a Windoze OS in a VM I'd have to pay M$ for another OS and I'm not prepared to do that.